# Installing Scratch 2 in ubuntu

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg

have been trying to download scratch 2 on ubuntu howere I got this far and I dont know what to do:

```
getlibs -1 libhal-storage.so.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
getopt: unrecognized option '-1'
No match for libhal-storage.so.1
No packages to install
```

what to I do???
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Than do it, install `lib32z1`, `lib32ncurses5`, `lib32bz2-1.0`, the answer is already in the error message.

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
```

Comment: Also, I have ubuntu 14.0.4; shouldn't I have a newer  version of ia32-libs already installed. If so, what's it called?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

To install **Scratch 2 Offline version** it is necessary to:

1. install Adobe Air
2. install Scrath 2 with Adobe Air

But it is a nightmare to install Adobe Air.

Luckily I've found [here (in last part of the page)](https://diocesanos.es/blogs/equipotic/2017/09/15/instalacion-de-scratch-2-offline-con-adobe-air-en-ubuntu/) a small script that runs  perfectly and does everything on **18.04.2 LTS** for me.

### So the solution is :

1. create this script

   ```
    #!/bin/bash

    if [ $EUID -ne 0 ]; then
       echo "To be launched with sudo" 1>&2
       exit 1
    fi

    echo ">> Remove previous versions..."
    apt-get -y --purge remove adobeair
    rm -rf /opt/adobe-air-sdk
    rm /usr/share/applications/Scratch2.desktop

    CHKBITS=`uname -m`
    if [ $CHKBITS = "x86_64" ]; then
        echo ">> Installing dependencies 32bit..."
        apt-get -q update
        apt-get -q -y install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libxml2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 libqt4-qt3support:i386 libgnome-keyring0:i386 libnss-mdns:i386 libnss3:i386
    fi

    echo ">> Link Gnome libraries..."
    ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0
    ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0

    echo ">> Download Adobe Air SDK..."
    wget -q http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/lin/download/2.6/AdobeAIRSDK.tbz2
    mkdir /opt/adobe-air-sdk
    tar jxf AdobeAIRSDK.tbz2 -C /opt/adobe-air-sdk

    echo ">> Download Air runtime/SDK from Archlinux..."
    wget -q https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/snapshot/adobe-air.tar.gz
    tar xvf adobe-air.tar.gz -C /opt/adobe-air-sdk
    chmod +x /opt/adobe-air-sdk/adobe-air/adobe-air

    echo ">> Download Scratch2..."
    mkdir /opt/adobe-air-sdk/scratch
    wget -q -O /opt/adobe-air-sdk/scratch/scratch.air https://scratch.mit.edu/scratchr2/static/sa/Scratch-456.0.4.air

    echo ">> Creating launcher..."
    unzip -j /opt/adobe-air-sdk/scratch/scratch.air icons/AppIcon128.png -d /opt/adobe-air-sdk/scratch/
    cat << _EOF_ > /usr/share/applications/Scratch2.desktop
    [Desktop Entry]
    Encoding=UTF-8
    Version=1.0
    Type=Application
    Exec=/opt/adobe-air-sdk/adobe-air/adobe-air /opt/adobe-air-sdk/scratch/scratch.air
    Icon=/opt/adobe-air-sdk/scratch/AppIcon128.png
    Terminal=false
    Name=Scratch 2
    Comment=Programación visual con Scatch 2.0
    Categories=Application;Education;Development;ComputerScience;
    MimeType=application/x-scratch-project
    _EOF_
    chmod +x /usr/share/applications/Scratch2.desktop

    echo ">> the END!"
   ```
2. execute this script with `sudo`
3. now it should be installed, just search **Scratch 2** in your application and launch it !

[image]

Comment: oups, I finaly found that this answer was already existing [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/913912/32413)