# Adobe Air error when installing Scratch 2

Tags: 16.04, flash, adobe-air

I installed successfully Adobe Air on Ubuntu 16.04 64bit.

Nonetheless I encountered a problem. When I try to install Scratch 2 I get this message:

> Sorry, an error has occurred.
>
> The application could not be installed because the file installer is damaged. Try obtaining a new installer file from the application author.

I don't understand where is the problem,

Can you help me?

Comment: I tried this but I get the same error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

had the same problem, I did get it to work though when I used an older Version of scratch. Starting with version 456.0.1 Scratch needs a newer version of Adobe Air, whitch isn't available for linux afaik.

You can download version 455 from 
https://scratch.mit.edu/scratchr2/static/sa/Scratch-455.air

That is the latest version I did get to work, updating it is not possible, so one has to put up with the annoying "A newer versio of Scratch is available" popup when you start the program, but updating fails with the error message you reported.

Hope that helps!