# Launching Scratch in Ubuntu problem

Tags: 16.04

[How to install Scratch 2 on Ubuntu 16.10. or 17.04 (64bit)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913892/how-to-install-scratch-2-on-ubuntu-16-10-or-17-04-64bit/913912)

Have followed the code by Martin but permission is denied and no such file exists messages appear.

The first bit of code seems to have worked so I have the scratch.air file

Any help appreciated  - code I've tried is below :

Create launcher:

```
$ cat << _EOF_ > /usr/share/applications/Scratch2.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/adobe-air-sdk/adobe-air/adobe-air /opt/adobe-air-sdk/scratch/Scratch-456.0.1.air
Icon=/opt/adobe-air-sdk/scratch/scratch.png
Terminal=false
Name=Scratch 2
Comment=Programming system and content development tool
Categories=Application;Education;Development;ComputerScience;
MimeType=application/x-scratch-project
_EOF_

$ chmod +x /usr/share/applications/Scratch2.desktop
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the /usr/share/applications directory is owned by root - you won't be able to `cat` to a file there without sudo. You can either modify the here-doc command to

```
cat << _EOF_ | sudo tee /usr/share/applications/Scratch2.desktop
```

or just use an editor to create the .desktop file instead

```
sudoedit /usr/share/applications/Scratch2.desktop
```

---

FWIW I don't believe `.desktop` files need execute permission, but if they did you would need `sudo` to change that as well

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/share/applications/Scratch2.desktop
```

Comment: Thanks for that steeldriver. A bit confused now though.What do I need to type insteadof the grey box in my question then?

Comment: You can **either** type `sudoedit /usr/share/applications/Scratch2.desktop` and **then** type everything from `[Desktop Entry]` to `MimeType=application/x-scratch-project` into the editor **or** simply replace the `>` in the first line of your existing command by `| sudo tee`. Alternatively, drop to a root shell at the start using `sudo -i` and then type everything as-is. I would omit the `chmod` command altogether, for the reason I mentioned above.

Comment: Ah! Asks for password then opens GNU nano 2.5.3.  with ta terminal-looking window. If I try pasting the code again nothing happens after the MimeType line.

Comment: You use the Ctrl+Key combinations indicated at the bottom of the screen to save and exit - see [How to edit files in a terminal with nano?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54221/how-to-edit-files-in-a-terminal-with-nano?)

Comment: I'm sorry I have no idea why I have a new windownow and what has happened.

Comment: I just want a desktop icon showing Scratch

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much for this answer. It worked perfectly.
I'm  posting this as an answer since it is clear-er for me/others to see how easy it is.

As stated in the comments, I replaced the line provided in the previous answer for the original command given then I just copied the rest of the command. Thanks again... It worked beautifully. I also changed the Scratch version to download. I first installed the version(number 456.0.1) but the updated just downloads and does not installs it.... I checked the current version -456.0.4- on the website and I changed it accordingly to all the commands to install it.

```
cat << _EOF_ | sudo tee /usr/share/applications/Scratch2.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/adobe-air-sdk/adobe-air/adobe-air /opt/adobe-air-sdk/scratch/Scratch-456.0.4.air
Icon=/opt/adobe-air-sdk/scratch/scratch.png
Terminal=false
Name=Scratch 2
Comment=Programming system and content development tool
Categories=Application;Education;Development;ComputerScience;
MimeType=application/x-scratch-project
_EOF_
```