# How to install scratch 2 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, 18.04

Yesterday i was trying to install scratch on my ubuntu desktop and followed this tutorial [How to install Scratch 2 on Ubuntu 16.10. or 17.04 (64bit)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913892/how-to-install-scratch-2-on-ubuntu-16-10-or-17-04-64bit/913912#913912)

And everything was just successfully installed but when i run scratch it shows me only heading and white screen.
It was not starting.
Can someone give me updated instructions on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

... and this works for me on ubuntu 18.04 (64bit)

1. install necesary i386 libraries

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libxml2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 libqt4-qt3support:i386 libgnome-keyring0:i386 libnss-mdns:i386 libnss3:i386
   ```
2. make keyring visible for Adobe Air

   ```
   $ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0
   $ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0
   ```
3. Download Adobe Air

   ```
   $ cd ~/Downloads
   $ wget http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/lin/download/2.6/AdobeAIRSDK.tbz2
   $ sudo mkdir /opt/adobe-air-sdk
   $ sudo tar jxf AdobeAIRSDK.tbz2 -C /opt/adobe-air-sdk
   ```
4. Download Air runtime/SDK from Archlinux

   ```
   $ wget https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/snapshot/adobe-air.tar.gz
   $ sudo tar xvf adobe-air.tar.gz -C /opt/adobe-air-sdk
   $ sudo chmod +x /opt/adobe-air-sdk/adobe-air/adobe-air
   ```
5. Get actual scratch file URL from https://scratch.mit.edu/scratch2download/

   ```
   $ sudo mkdir /opt/adobe-air-sdk/scratch
   $ wget https://scratch.mit.edu/scratchr2/static/sa/Scratch-456.0.1.air
   $ sudo cp Scratch-456.0.1.air /opt/adobe-air-sdk/scratch/
   $ cp Scratch-456.0.1.air /tmp/
   $ cd /tmp/
   $ unzip /tmp/Scratch-456.0.1.air
   $ sudo cp /tmp/icons/AppIcon128.png /opt/adobe-air-sdk/scratch/scratch.png
   ```
6. Create Desktop Shortcut

   ```
   $ sudo cat << _EOF_ > /usr/share/applications/Scratch2.desktop
   [Desktop Entry]
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   Exec=/opt/adobe-air-sdk/adobe-air/adobe-air /opt/adobe-air-sdk/scratch/Scratch-456.0.1.air
   Icon=/opt/adobe-air-sdk/scratch/scratch.png
   Terminal=false
   Name=Scratch 2
   Comment=Programming system and content development tool
   Categories=Application;Education;Development;ComputerScience;
   MimeType=application/x-scratch-project
   _EOF_

   $ sudo chmod +x /usr/share/applications/Scratch2.desktop
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I found an [Ubuntu educational fork](http://www.ac-grenoble.fr/maths/scratch/scratch.zip) for Scratch 3 beta version. You just need to change language from french to english =)

For scratch 1.4 just type:

```
 sudo apt-get install scratch
```

I'm not in informatics, but I think in the 1.4 version a library like Qt4 is missing for the fonts.

For Scratch 2, I didn't manage to install Adobe Air 20, it bugs too much on Wine install :/

Please don't over spam this french academy, as I don't believe at all their Bandwith to handle World's download neither a town's download. Just add the download to a normal download website for Ubuntu packages.

More over there must be an official link outside of the one I proposed as it's official [Scratch 3 official beta version online](https://llk.github.io/scratch-gui/master/) works with Linux. Must be somewhere in GitHub or something?

Answer (score 1):

Install adobe air as state on https://www.noobslab.com/2015/05/adobeair-is-now-available-for-ubuntu.html

```
wget -O adobe-air_amd64.deb http://drive.noobslab.com/data/apps/AdobeAir/adobeair_2.6.0.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i adobe-air_amd64.deb 
sudo apt install -f
```

Install pixbuf stuff

```
 sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386
```

Install scratch (use 455, newer versions need newer AIR)

```
wget https://scratch.mit.edu/scratchr2/static/sa/Scratch-455.air
```

Start

```
/opt/adobe-air-sdk/adobe-air/adobe-air ./Scratch-455.air
```

See also [How to install Scratch 2 on Ubuntu 16.10. or 17.04 (64bit)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913892/how-to-install-scratch-2-on-ubuntu-16-10-or-17-04-64bit)

Answer (score 0):

To bring Jerare's comment (consider posting an answer next time; you may get credit for it) further into the light, Scratux is a Linux build of the latest Scratch Desktop (currently 3.10.2) and is available on the Ubuntu snap store.  I had to go through those Adobe Air installation steps on a previous Ubuntu installation; this is much simpler!